# Des-Seleccionar, programáticamente una fila en dojox/grid/Datagrid

Tags: javascript

Tengo un datagrid hecho con dojo framework. Me gustaría saber cómo puedo des-seleccionar mediante javascript una fila arbitrariamente. Al inicio, tengo la teoría de que podría ser más o menos así:

```
    var seleccion = miDataGrid.getSelected();

    dojo.forEach(seleccion, function(item){
        if (se_me_pega_la_gana)
            item.set('selected', false);
    });
```

Pero, al parecer el item/fila no cuenta con una función set. Quizá deba abordar esto de otra manera, aunque no se me ocurre cómo. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Era casi obvio (más o menos). Lo anoto aquí para cuando se me vaya a olvidar:

```
var fila = grid.getItem(indice_de_item_a_desmarcar);
grid.selection.setSelected(fila, false);
```

Comment: Deberías marcar tu respuesta como válida

Comment: Cierto. Gracias.